# save id from <select-box> from two posible forms in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to get the id from one select box, the thing is that the select box change from one form to another depending the option, the problem is that im using the same metho change for the two  and the id disappear when i change from one form to another.

I've been trying to change to set manually the form to the correspond id but then have problems of 'undefined'

## [image: Form 1, when id is ok]

[image: Here the id it's loses]

```
ticket.html

<div class="row animated fadeIn" [hidden]="isSugerir">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row" [formGroup]="formaTicket" >

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">

        <div class="control">
            <span >Categoria:
              <dx-select-box formControlName="fcCategoriaTicketId" [dataSource]="categoriasTicketsBd" noDataText="No hay datos que mostrar"
              displayExpr="nombre" valueExpr="id" [searchEnabled]="true" placeholder="Seleccione una Categoria"
              (displayValueChange)="OnChangeScreenByCategory($event)">
              </dx-select-box>
            </span>
        </div>

      </div>

<div class="row animated fadeIn" [hidden]="!isSugerir">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row" [formGroup]="formaSugerirEmpresa" >

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-4" >

        <div class="control">
            <span style="padding: 20px;">Categoria:
              <dx-select-box formControlName="fcCategoriaSugId" [dataSource]="categoriasTicketsBd" noDataText="No hay datos que mostrar"
              displayExpr="nombre" valueExpr="id" [searchEnabled]="true" placeholder="Seleccione una Categoria"
              (displayValueChange)="OnChangeScreenByCategory($event)">
              </dx-select-box>
            </span>
        </div>

      </div>

ticket.ts
OnChangeScreenByCategory(event) {
        this.nombreCategoria = event;
        console.log(this.nombreCategoria);
        console.log(this.formaTicket.controls.fcCategoriaTicketId.value);


        if (this.nombreCategoria === 'Sugerencia de Empresa') {

          this.isSugerir = true;

        } else {
          this.isSugerir = false;
        }

        console.log('Sugerir Empresa? ', this.isSugerir);
       }
```

Comment: I dont understand your problem, i think you need to clarify it a bit, also i noticed in your code you are trying to get a value from a formGroup i think, for that you need to access it via formgroup.value.yourcontrolname

Comment: Additionally, move your code to the question and remove the screenshots of the code